# Trying to retrieve Http JSON from angular service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set up a service that will perform an Http get and return JSON data to the caller. I think I have everything set up correctly based on examples I'm following, but the compiler won't allow me to call the service to get the data. Tells me I'm trying to call a void function but I'm explicitly returning a value in the that function. Here's the code for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AircraftInfoService {
  aircraft: string;
  api = 'https://<notshow>/api/PApps_AircraftInfo?apikey=<notshown>';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {   
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('aircraftInfoservice');
  }

  getAircraft() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.api).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log('aircraft: ', res );
      return res;
    })
  }
}
```

And here is where I'm trying to call the service in app.compontent.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  className: string;
  isAuthenticated$:         Observable<boolean>;
  appSettings: AppSettings;
  appSettingsSub: Subscription;
  themeClass: string;
  _wing: string;
  _theme: string;
  aircraftDB: string;


  constructor(
    private titleService: TitleService,
    public appSettingsService: AppSettingsService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    public aircraftInfoService: AircraftInfoService,
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private adalService: AdalService,      
    private logger: LogService,
    private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer,
    @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: WebStorageService
    ){

    adalService.init(environment.config);


    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      "historical-tracking-black-48",
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/historical-tracking-black-48.svg")
);
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      "historical-tracking-black-48-inactive",
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/historical-tracking-black-48-inactive.svg")
    );
  } 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.className = this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];

    this.appSettings = this.appSettingsService.behaviorSubject.getValue();
    this.appSettingsSub =     this.appSettingsService.behaviorSubject.asObservable().subscribe(value => {
      this.appSettings = value;
      this._wing = this.appSettings.wing;
      this.themeClass = this.appSettings.theme;
    }); 

    this.aircraftDB = this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft();

    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    this.logger.debug(this.className, "adal userInfo: ",     this.adalService.userInfo);

  }
```

The line

```
this.aircraftDB = this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft()
```

is causing the problem:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will return the `Subscription` first. so you are getting that error. You can solve it in two ways:

```
getAircraft() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.api).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log('aircraft: ', res );
        return res;
    })
```

Change the type of `aircraftDB` to `any` `aircraftDB: any`. But that's not the right way. The other way is to return the subscription as follows:

```
getAircraft() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.api);
}
```

In your **component.ts**, You can subscribe it and assign the `res` to `this.aircraftDB`

```
this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft().subscribe((res)=>{
    console.log('aircraft: ', res );
    this.aircraftDB = res;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
Change into your service

```
    getAircraft() {
      this.httpClient.get(this.api).pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          return res.toString();
        })
      );
   }
```

Option 2

return the observable object from service and subscribe it into your AppComponnet

```
  getAircraft() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.api);
  }
```

and in AppComponent

```
this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft().subscribe((res: any) {
  console.log('Response', res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Question in first place `why do you want to reference your service ?`. If all you want is to invoke a `service` in component, all you should do in `subscribe` to it. 
Because an `http` call is `async` i.e. `you don't get the data right away... you have to make the requst and await the response` this is where `Observable` come in picture.

So, good solution is to change change your service implementation slightly, it should return an `observable<datatype>`

```
getAircraft():Observable<any[]> {
    this.httpClient.get(this.api).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log('aircraft: ', res );
      return res;
    });
}
```

and then in your `component` you merely have to `subscribe` to it

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
   this.aircraftInfoService.getAircraft().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.aircraftDB =  data;
   });
  ...
}
```